# Unity: C# Spell System

Tags: unity, c#

I couldn't find any proper tutorials in the internet how to make one so I tried it myself. I've written a base "Skill" class with methods like `Cast()`, `DealFlatDamage()`, `ShootProjectile()` and they all work so far. But I also wanted to implement trigger methods for passive spells: `OnDeath()`, `OnKilled()`, `OnProjectileHit()`.

**First Question:** Is this a wrong way to go? Because I couldn't find anything like this in the internet.

**Second Question:** The idea was to create new classes inheriting from this base class and the base class calling all the "On..."-methods of each derived class. How can I do this?

Would appreciate help!

Comment: "Is this a wrong way to go?" - if it works for you, it works. "idea was to create new classes inheriting..." - you could do this without inheritance using Unity's SendMessage system, but if you want to do it with inheritance "How can I do this?" is a question for StackOverflow, since class/interface inheritance is vanilla C#, no game-specific knowledge needed.

Comment: This topic on bytecode might be of interest: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/bytecode.html it shows how to create a spell system that can be easily expanded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no right or wrong way to do this, but here is an alternative approach.

```
interface IOnDeath
{
    void Action( /*some context here*/ );
}

class Skill
{
    public List<IOnDeath> OnDeathEffects;
}

class OnDeathNova : IOnDeath
{
    public void Action(...)
    {
        /* creates an outward facing ring of projectiles */
    }
}

...
    skill.OnDeathEffects.Add(new OnDeathNova());
...
```

This gives you a very dynamic approach, and lets you modify things at run-time. Maybe you want to make a spell deal double damage when a buff is applied. Maybe you want to have it bounce. All these things could be hardcoded into a single class, but it would get messy fast. This approach lets you give each "effect" their own separate implementation.

Comment: I don't know if I understood it right. Would this mean I just call a method in the Skill class if my character dies?: 
`public void CallOnDeathEffects()
{
    foreach(IOnDeath IOD in OnDeathEffects)
    {
        IOD.Action();
    }
}
`

Comment: Something along those lines yes.